# Why must USB low-speed devices use a captive cable?

Tags: usb, cables, capacitance

The USB 2.0 spec says: "A low-speed device is required to have a captive cable." However, I can't find a good explanation for why this is the case. I have seen hints towards two possible explanations:

1. To prevent users from accidentally using a (non-captive) low-speed cable with a full-speed or high-speed device. However, there is an error in this logic: To achieve that, the spec would only have to demand that low-speed cables must be captive. It would not have to demand that low-speed devices use a captive cable, the difference being that a low-speed device could use a non-captive full/high-speed cable.
2. Differences in cable capacitance. Section 7.1.2.1 says: "A low-speed device (including cable)
   may have a capacitance of as little as 200 pF and as much as 450 pF". Unfortunately I found it hard to find numbers for high-speed cables. Things get more complex because different cable lengths exist, but then, I don't understand why the spec disallows using these cables altogether instead of saying, if a low-speed devices has a B-receptacle then it must handle all standard cables, and only if it can't do that a captive cable is required. Also, in case standard cables have a capacitance that already exceeds 450pF (as noted, I don't know the actual numbers), then hub drivers are strong enough to handle that because they must (for fullspeed), so they could do the same for lowspeed -- and for the device, again, a captive cable could be required only if its driver is too weak for the capacitance range of standard cables.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason is, as in your first explanation, to prevent the accidental use of a low-speed cable with a full- or high-speed device.

Yes, you're technically correct that they could simply mandate that low-speed cables be made captive - but having removable cables being used on a low-speed device would create a market for cheap uncertified cables being sold with (or not sold with) an "only for use with low-speed devices" warning that people could ignore and use on other devices.

Making low-speed devices use captive cables simply removes that market and any chance of ever using the wrong cable.

Comment: excellently put! All the "this cable should not exist" restrictions of USB (e.g. the "USB-A to USB-A plug cables shouldn't exist" to avoid confusing devices with hosts) is meant to protect the USB "ecosystem"; opening up a market for low-grade cables would've been bad in the day when USB2.0 "Full-Speed capable" cabling was noticeable more pricey than a simple four-lead that would suffice for e.g. a low-speed mouse.

Comment: Vendors of USB powered devices often use USB-B, the square plug and socket, so USB-A and USB-C cannot be used by accident as there is no intent to send data either way.

Comment: If a vendor ignores the spec and is willing to produce "bad" cables with a B plug, what prevents the same vendor from ignoring the spec and making a lowspeed device with a B receptacle?

Comment: Devices need vendor/device IDs in order to identify them, and they have to be obtained and could be withdrawn for "rogue" devices. Anyone can make a cable.

Comment: Another reason came to my mind. A single rogue vendor making a lowspeed device with a B receptable does not yet do significant (visible) harm to the ecosystem since every combination will still work. Another vendor could then make low-grade cables that only work with these devices, and then harm is done. BUT: It takes two rogue vendors in tandem for that, while if lowspeed devices with B receptacles were allowed, a single rogue vendor could do harm already by producing bad cables. This is compounded by the fact you stated about cables not having vendor IDs.

Comment: @Finbarr Anyone can make a Vendor ID, too.